# Need help to solve the next limit

Tags: limits

I'm trying to compute the limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n!\cdot(3n)!}{(4n)!}$$

Comment: Your link doesn't work. Try typing it out even if the formatting is poor.

Comment: 5xum already do it,thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately he retained an $x$ in the limit!

Comment: @Frank Indeed I did, on purpose. I edited the post to make it readable, but left the contents undisturbed for the OP to comment. He can fix the $n$ to $x$ easily.

Comment: OK, I understand - I don't know anything about the etiquette of editing I'm afraid!

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1464006/what-is-the-limit-of-n-cdot-2n-3n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**$$\frac{(3n)!}{(4n)!} = \frac{1\cdot 2 \cdot 3\cdots 3n}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3 \cdots 3n\cdot (3n+1) \cdot (3n+2) \cdots (4n-1)\cdot 4n}=\frac{1}{(3n+1)(3n+2)\cdots 4n}$$

Comment: hi,thanks but what about:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{n!}{(3n+1)...4n}$$ 
what i need to do now?

Comment: Well, my answer is just a hint, so this is where you should stare at the equation for a while and see what comes up. In this case, both the denominator and numerator have $n$ factors. Try writing the fraction as a product of $n$ fractions and see what you can discover about each. The first is $\frac1{3n+1}$ which limits to $0$, if the others are bounded, you are done!

Comment: whan i tried to continue:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{(4n)\cdot(3n+1)\cdot....\cdot1}$$

but this is limit to 0 no to inf,where is my mistake?

Comment: @5xum, when setting $n=1$ it goes to $\frac 1 {3(1)+1}=\frac 1 4$.  Then $n=2 \mapsto \frac 2{7\cdot 8}$, $n=3 \mapsto \frac 6 {10\cdot 11\cdot 12 }$, et cetera.  The denominator appears to be increasing faster than the numerator.

Comment: Where is the first $n!$?

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{n!(3n)!}{4n!} = \frac{n(n-1) ... 1}{4n(4n-1)...(3n+1) } \leq \frac{1}{3n+1} \rightarrow 0 \quad \textrm{as} \quad n \rightarrow \infty. $$

Comment: That inequality needs some justification, but the idea is quite alright I think.

Comment: The only justification required is that $n \leq 4n, n-1 \leq 4n-1,....$, or equivalently $1 \leq 4$...

Comment: Got it..thanks!

Comment: @Frank Yes, it was not a criticism, I think your answer is very good. I just commented so OP would not think that he can write the inequality without thought.

Comment: @5xum OK, I understand :)